# What happens when angular HostBinding is used along with directive assignment?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I've written a directive in angular that disables or enables a button after validating an object.
But the button also has some other simple validation requirements which are directly supplied to the "disabled" directive as value.
Example code html:

```
<button (click)="onSave()"
    [disabled]="validation1() || !validation2()"
    [validProperty]="myObject.property">Save</button>
```

This is my directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeType } from '../../types/data.types';

@Directive({
    selector: '[validProperty]'
})
export class ValidateDirective implements OnChanges {

    @HostBinding('disabled') disabled: boolean;
    @Input('validProperty') property: SomeType[];

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.disabled = !this.validateProperty(this.property);
    }

    private validateProperty(property: SomeType[]): boolean {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Currently, my button only considers validations submitted to [disabled] and not my directive, eventhough control reaches my directive(I've used devtools breakpoints to check). How do i make it consider both [disabled] validations and my directive hostbinding? Kindof like an or operator.
Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: `[disabled]="validation1() || !validation2() || myObject.property"` ?

Comment: @Stavm, myObject.property is not a boolean. It's an array of objects that needs to be validated. I'm using a directive to validate it.

Comment: then create a validating method for that array, the point was, avoid creating a race condition which only works due to angular implementation details (which runs after which) and move all the logic to disable a button, to a single spot

Comment: I could write validation in a method. I just wanted to use a directive. So, is it not possible to achieve this? @Stavm